# Excel: the first and last time per day

Tags: microsoft-excel, timestamp

I have an Excel file with timestamps and I want to find the first and last time per day,
My spreadsheet has thousands of rows, but here is an extract:

| Startup Time | Shutdown Time |
| --- | --- |
| 29.10.2020 15:59 | 29.10.2020 16:04 |
| 29.10.2020 16:05 | 29.10.2020 16:08 |
| 29.10.2020 16:10 | 29.10.2020 16:11 |
| 29.10.2020 16:38 | 29.10.2020 16:45 |
| 29.10.2020 16:45 | 29.10.2020 16:54 |
| 29.10.2020 16:54 | 29.10.2020 17:30 |
| 04.11.2020 08:34 | 04.11.2020 11:26 |
| 11.11.2020 11:37 | 11.11.2020 15:09 |
| 19.11.2020 07:49 | 19.11.2020 15:08 |
| 17.03.2021 10:26 | 17.03.2021 10:27 |
| 17.03.2021 07:28 | 17.03.2021 08:31 |
| 17.03.2021 17:53 | 17.03.2021 20:09 |

it must be displayed in this way:

| Date | Startup Time | Shutdown Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29.10.2020 | 15:59 | 17:30 |
| 04.11.2020 | 08:34 | 11:26 |
| 11.11.2020 | 11:37 | 15:09 |
| 19.11.2020 | 07:49 | 15:08 |
| 17.03.2021 | 07:28 | 20:09 |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: what about startup 17.03.2021 23:53 and shutdown 18.03.2021 00:10?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no version constraints, as indicated by your tags,

***Edit:** and also assuming that Startup-Shutdown times do not span midnight*
you can use the following:

- I `Name`'d the data table `Times`.

In some single cell:

```
=LET(
    t, TOCOL(Times),
    dt, INT(t),
    u, SORT(UNIQUE(dt)),
    ma, BYROW(u, LAMBDA(arr, MAX(FILTER(t, arr = dt)))),
    mi, BYROW(u, LAMBDA(arr, MIN(FILTER(t, arr = dt)))),
    VSTACK(
        {"Date", "Startup Time", "Shutdown Time"},
        HSTACK(u, mi, ma)
    )
)
```

and the results will spill into the adjacent rows/columns.

- `TOCOL` unpivots the two columns into one.
- `dt` returns only the dates without the times.
- `u` returns a sorted list of the distinct dates
- `ma` returns the maximum time for a date (Shutdown).
- `mi` returns the minimum time for a date (Startup).
- Since Excel stores date/time as numbers, you will need to format the output columns appropriately.

***Output from your data***
[image]

***Note:** If your times should span midnight, how would you want that shown?*

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But how (and where) can I add this code?

Comment: @Joao as I wrote, you  enter it in some cell. However, if your system uses semicolons instead of commas to delimit arguments, you will need to make that change yourself.

Comment: ...but, you'll need a fairly recent version of Excel (2021 or 365) to support the dynamic array functions involved. Without that, generate a list of the dates involved and use the `MAXIFS()` and `MINIFS()` functions (requires Excel 2019 or later) and failing that there is a way of using `SUMPRODUCT()` wrapped inside a `MAX()` and a `MIN()` to get what you are after.

Comment: @DMM He has 365. On a since deleted screenshot the error message he posted is what you see if you use incorrect separators in the `LET` function.

Comment: @Ron, thanks for noting that. I do think that one of the issues with the "microsoft-excel" tag is that the 2021/365 versions are so different from what went before that almost the first question is "dynamic or legacy?". You are obviously a bit more proficient than I at knowing how to read the clues as to the answer. An issue for the meta, perhaps?